# How to make an arr of drawables in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've been trying to use android studio to make an app with an Array of drawables so that you can traverse it with forwards and backwards buttons, most of the rest of the code is finished, but the line where I declare the drawable object ima it thorws an error saying drawable cannot be conversted into int, can somebody please help me with this?

````
 buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index++;
                if(index > imageList1.size() -1){
                    index = 0;
                }
                Drawable ima = getResources().getDrawable(imageArray[index], getTheme());

                image.setImageDrawable(ima);
```
`
````

Comment: How is `imageArray` defined and populated?

Comment: defined:     private Drawable[] imageArray;


populated:         imageArray = new Drawable[]{
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cama),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.computer),
        };

Comment: Why did you put the code in a comment? Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```java
Drawable ima = getResources().getDrawable(imageArray[index], getTheme());
```

with:

```java
Drawable ima = imageArray[index];
```

Your `imageArray` is an array of `Drawable`, not an array of drawable resource IDs.